Isogonal lines and an ellipse
Take two lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ with intersection $A$.
We say the lines $AM$ and $AN$ are isogonal with respect to the lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ if $AM$ is the reflection of $AN$ about the bisector of an angle made between $l_1$ and $l_2$.
I was given the following problem. If $M$ and $N$ are on the same side of both $l_1$ and $l_2$ then:

Prove that the lines $AM$ and $AN$ are isogonal with respect to $l_1$ and $l_2$ if and only if $$\min_{P\in l_1} |MP|+|NP| =\min_{P\in l_2} |MP|+|NP| $$

My attempt to solve this found the equivalent problem, if $M$ and $N$ are on the same side of both $l_1$ and $l_2$ then:

Prove that the lines $AM$ and $AN$ are isogonal with respect to $l_1$ and $l_2$ if and only if there is an ellipse tangent to $l_1$ and $l_2$ with focal points $M$ and $N$ .

I think the solution will use the reflection property of the ellipse but I couldn't chase the angles to the solution.
Any help is appreciated!

This could help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323574/equal-angles-formed-by-the-tangent-lines-to-an-ellipse-and-the-lines-through-the
